# @slot error: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I used @slot in laravel and just have some question.

Well in my `index.blade` php I use :

```
@component('components.alert')
    @slot('title') hi
    @slot('body','test1111')
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

which return nice, but after I change it into  this

```
@component('components.alert')
    @slot('title','hi')
    @slot('body','test1111')
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

It said :

> array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Here is my `components.alert` :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="alert-title" name="{{$Paneltitle}}">{{ $Paneltitle }}</div>
    {{ $body }}
</div>
```

Anyone can explain to me please? Why these happen, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the @endslot directive from your index.blade file:

```
@component('components.alert')
    @slot('title','hi')
    @slot('body','test1111')
@endcomponent
```

Comment: is it good to making a template and use slot to assign their name ?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to pass the name of the slot.